# Does Qt support Wi-Fi Direct / P2P connections on mobile platforms?

Tags: qt, mobile, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct

I would like to write a cross-platform mobile app based on Qt which is able to discover other devices reachable via Wi-Fi running the same app. If such devices are found they should be able to communicate with each other in an ad-hoc mannor without requiring any user (inter-)actions.

So my question is:

Does Qt support Wi-Fi Direct communication out of the box in general (i.e. is there any API for these kind of p2p connections), and if so, is this feature also available on mobile platforms supported by Qt? If there is no out of the box solution, can it be implemented with the existing Qt Wi-Fi networking API?

Comment: No, there are no such classes in Qt.